# Подробная БД по странам мира

Tags: база-данных

Коллеги! Просьба дать ссылку на рабочую БД (открытую), содержащую полную информацию по России (области, районы, города и мелкие нас.п.) и другим странам. Не уверен, что навигационные БД подойдут: нужно административное деление типа область->район->город.

Comment: [кладр](https://kladr-api.ru/)?

Comment: google geolocation api ?

Comment: >Просьба дать ссылку на рабочую БД (открытую), содержащую полную информацию по России 

И ещё голубой вертолёт, из которого мороженое бесплатно раздают.
Совсем уже кукукнулись?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно по России для этого используется [КЛАДР](http://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/), сейчас внедряют еще ФИАС, только сегодня [статья на хабре проскакивала.](http://habrahabr.ru/company/hflabs/blog/230823/)

Насколько я знаю по многим другим странам таких данных не существует.